# The function append does not add to my list, but rather changes the original

Tags: python, append

```py
import datetime 
from datetime import datetime 
A = True 
while True: 
    try:
        if A == True:
            input_user_bd = input('inter your barth day and your name(dd-mm-yyyy,the name):')
        else:
            input_user_bd = input('add your barth day and your name to the list '
                                  'dd-mm-yyyy,the name)\nif you want to delete the list enter(clear):')
        date,name = input_user_bd.split(',')
        bd = datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
        break
    except ValueError or AttributeError:
        print('error')



    def calculate_age(bd):
        today = datetime.now()
        return today.year -  bd
    calculate_age(bd.year)



    def print_age(th_name,age):
        print(th_name,'you are',age,"years old")
    print_age(name,calculate_age(bd.year))



    people = {
        'the name':[],
        'the date':[]
    }
    people['the name'].append(name)
    people['the date'].append(date)
    print(people)

    A = False
    if input_user_bd == 'clear':
        break
```

The following are the command line inputs and outputs:

> inter your barth day and your name(dd-mm-yyyy,the name):11-11-2001,a
>
> a you are 22 years old
>
> {'the name': ['a'], 'the date': ['11-11-2001']}
>
> add your barth day and your name to the list dd-mm-yyyy,the name)
>
> if you want to delete the list enter(clear):11-11-2001,AA
>
> AA you are 22 years old
>
> {'the name': ['AA'], 'the date': ['11-11-2001']}
>
> add your barth day and your name to the list dd-mm-yyyy,the name)
>
> if you want to delete the list enter(clear):

Comment: Could you clean up your post? It's not well-formatted, which makes it difficult to read. For example, some of the code isn't in the code box.

Comment: The code is also not properly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lists should be initialised outside of the while loop. So you should move the following before the while loop:

```py
    people = {
        'the name':[],
        'the date':[]
    }
```

Otherwise, as your code is written, you are recreating new lists every time.